# iOS Remote Notification Action Buttons not always present

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit

After following all the instructions presented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html) the Apple Watch notification does not consistently show the action button I have set in the notification settings during remote notification registration.

I am using Pushwoosh as a service and made sure that the remote notification JSON data I am sending to Pushwoosh have the correct parameters, and the one I am receiving on the device from APNS has the proper aps-alert-category structure and contents.

I can find no pattern on when it does or does not appear, so I'm at a dead end. Does anyone have an idea why the action buttons do not appear all the time, even on the same device?

Comment: Forget the Apple Watch. The action buttons are not showing up consistently on iPhone 6 with iOS 8.2

Comment: @AnandBiligiri Have you been able to confirm this?

Comment: @AnandKumar the action buttons are showing up properly. As mentioned in the answer for this questions, the categories were being overridden by some other part of the code. Once I fixed that, they show up consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the logs, it was discovered that the Pushwoosh_AUTO setting *true* on the plist file was causing the service to register its own categories to APNS, effectively often overwriting the categories specified in my app. Upon setting this to *false* the action button appears normally.